# FitNesse: Could not find class from Jar

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

We have been using FitNesse to run Jira API tests for couple years now. But from last couple of months it stopped working.

Here is what the setup look like:

```
C:  
    FitNesse  
        JiraLib -> Jar file  
        FitNesseRoot  
        fitnesse-standalone.jar
```

And this is what I have defined on the main root page:

```
variable defined: TEST_SYSTEM=slim  
classpath: C:\Fitnesse\JiraLib\JiraIntegrationReports.jar
```

Now when I run one of the method from the jar file, I am getting `Could not find class` and `The instance decisionTable_0.methodName. does not exist` errors.

And here is the execution log:

[image]

I have tried all the possible ways (with no luck) to fix this which includes-

- re-installed different versions FitNesse number of times
- re-compiled Java code and created Jar
- Tried running the tests using `Fit` instead `Slim`

Any thoughts around what's going on and how to fix it?

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: Any chance you remember what changed a couple of months when it didn't work anymore? You indicate you reinstalled FitNesse and recompiled code, so I assume you didn't change the FitNesse version. Did you change Java version, or did you upgrade Windows? Something must have changed, right?

Comment: Nope, nothing I can think of and that's what driving me crazy. I even tried with Java 14 but no luck.